# Casting a variable, not sure why it gives a ClassCastException

Tags: inheritance, casting

We have following code:

[image]

And we have this instruction:

```
mySub = (SubClass) mySuper;
```

To me this looks like a legal casting but it gives a ClassCastException. Why so?

Comment: You can cast an instance of a subclass to its superclass, but not vice versa.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen For example mySuper = (SuperClass) mySub ?

Comment: Downcasting from `Super` to `Sub` is fine as long as Super references a subclass object. In this case Super references a Super object..  If you have to downcast, do a type check

Comment: @Michiel Yes indeed.

Comment: @LewsTherin My comment is about the underlying instance, yours is about the reference type.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I actually don't see it. I'm talking about both: "Super references a subclass object". Reference type + referenced object.

Comment: @LewsTherin Since you've removed the *@RobbyCornelissen Really?* from your first comment, I gather that you actually do see it.

Comment: But that was before your reply :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)

From Oracle Docs..

Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. For example, the following code generates a ClassCastException:

```
 Object x = new Integer(0);
 System.out.println((String)x);

Eg:  Object x = new Integer(0);         //works fine 
     String s = (String)x;      //Will raise an exception here as Object 
                                    is not a subclass of String.
```